# lightswitch many to many checkbox filter

Tags: many-to-many, visual-studio-lightswitch

Hey guys I have a many to many checkbox where a user can select many cities. I have a dropdown list above for selected state. I want to bring back only the regions that belong to that state that is selected.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a List and Details Screen instead of a dropdown list? You would just need to add both the states and cities tables to the advanced data section.

However, if you really need to use a drop down box, it is very complex but can be done.
You will need to begin a new search screen and lay it out as follows:

[image: Screen layout]

Create a group to start. You will need to 'add data item...' and choose Property, StateTable. Name this 'State' and add it to the group.

Create a second group. Again 'add data item...' Choose Query, CitiesTable (All). Name this StateCities. In the side panel, click 'edit query' next to StateCities and set it up as follows:

[image: State Cities Query setup]

Return to your design screen by clicking the 'back to -screenname-' just above the filter statement. You should now see three bold items in the sidebar to the left. The first will be your StateTable, the second will be your StateCites query and the third will be your single State query.

[image: Left sidebar view]

Click the dropdown button for the StateCities query and you will see the query parameters at the bottom. You have a parameter called 'id'
Click on the Id parameter from the sidebar and change the parameter binding property (shown on the right hand side bar) to State.Id. If everything has been done correctly, this should hook up to your state query id field.

[image: Parameter pointing to query]

Once this is hooked up, you should be able to save your screen and run your program with the desired results!